# How to protect intellectual property in Azure Marketplace Virtual Machine Offers?

Tags: azure-marketplace

We are an ISV who offer a proprietary web application that can be installed anywhere: Window Server, Linux, Docker etc.

Normally, we would provide a license file that allows the web application to run past the 60 day trial period. The license file we issue is linked to a specific domain name, so the license file can't be copied and used for running the web application elsewhere.

We would like to offer the software via an Azure Marketplace Virtual Machine offering with a per-core, per-hour cost that is billed through Azure.

If we do this, how do we protect the software installed on the VM? What is to prevent someone from connecting to the VM and copying the software to a non-metered VM?

Is there some way for the web application to verify that it is running in a metered VM? Perhaps via the metadata service?

Comment: The only real solution is to prevent the user to install the program on their own servers.

Comment: Uh, well we aren't the first company to license software, so there are good tools available. Nothing is 100% fool proof of course, but this is straightforward question about the technical options available. Does the standard azure metadata service indicate that the VM is part of a specific offer, for example?

Comment: Your potential attackers aren't the first in cracking software either :D Reality is that, if your program can be installed anywhere the user wants, it can (and will) be cracked, no matter what. Probably you want to continue with your license file plus some online validation against your servers to avoid duplicate activations or something like that, but that only raises the bar. The final solution is to host the whole thing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution seems to be to use the Azure metadata service as an alternative to the license file.

The [attested data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service?tabs=linux#attested-data) endpoint provides a cryptographically-signed document that contains the SKU of the image from which the VM was created.

This allows the software to verify that it is running in a VM billed through Azure Marketplace.